# Fairly easy JQuery Input Selection location problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with getting my JQuery javascript code to apply to the select box elements that it is supposed to. What's happening is that the select boxes are not following the actions that are specified in the javascript code. They are simply staying disabled and checked (see code below) instead of changing based on the first checkbox's selection.

I believe it is a problem regarding how I specify the location of the select boxes in the javascript code, but I don't know how to go about fixing it. Then again, I could be wrong about that too.

If you have any insight on this or can correct the code, please do! Cheers.

---

### HTML:

```
<div class="medium_box">
    <form name="searchform" class="FECKsearch" method="get" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
        <input name="s" id="searchBox" class="input" type="text" value="" onfocus="myFocusHandler(this);" onblur="myBlurHandler(this);" size="18" maxlength="50">
        <input type="submit" name="searchsubmit" class="button" value="Go" />

        <span class="searcher">International: <input type="checkbox" id="International" checked="yes"></input></span>
        <span class="searcher1">Americas: <input type="checkbox" id="Americas" disabled checked="yes"></input></span>
        <span class="searcher1">Europe: <input type="checkbox" id="Europe" disabled checked="yes"></input></span>
        Asia: <input type="checkbox" id="Asia" disabled checked="yes"></input>
    </form> 
</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
$('#International').click(function() {
var paramChangeBoxes = $('input:checkbox');
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#Americas').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#Americas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#Europe').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#Europe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#Asia').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#Asia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
else {
    paramChangeBoxes.removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#Americas').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#Europe').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#Asia').removeAttr('disabled');

    }
});
```

---

## Update & Solution:

Cheers to [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763228/john) for the code `$('#International').live("click",function() {` which corrected the error of the JQuery code not functioning. Apparently if you are importing the code from a remote file you must include the "live" portion inside of your coding.

Thanks again John!

Comment: Maybe `.attr('disabled', false)` instead?

Comment: You're improperly setting the `checked` boolean attribute. Use `checked` instead of `checked="yes"`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ppaGa/ - your code works fine? can you confirm your jQuery is working?

Comment: No luck getting either of those to run the javascript, but thank you for the information on the `checked` attribute

Comment: @John here is a live test of the website: http://webid3.feckcorp.com

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you're wanting to happen when #International is clicked.  When it is checked you want others to be enabled and checked?  When it is unchecked you want others to be disabled and unchecked?  It appears to me that your code is doing exactly what you tell it to.

Comment: you are importing the jquery from a remote file? try change $('#International').click(function() { TO > $('#International').live("click",function() {

Comment: i do not see your jquery on this page src, where is it i am blind

Comment: @Charles Sprayberry - the code itself works as its supposed to, but for some reason or another (why I posted here) it doesn't want to work on my website.

Comment: @John it is located in the common.js (http://webid3.feckcorp.com/FECKCONTENT/themes/FECK_V2/scripts/common.js)

Comment: Erik I can not firstly find the jquery code been included, secondly use the live listener if you are importing for dynamic calls

Comment: that looks like the jquery include.. O-o

Comment: @John Your code worked! Using `$('#International').live("click",function() {` corrected the problem. Thank you!

Comment: i put the answer up, have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#International').live("click",function() {
var paramChangeBoxes = $('input:checkbox');
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#Americas').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#Americas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#Europe').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#Europe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#Asia').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#Asia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
else {
    paramChangeBoxes.removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#Americas').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#Europe').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#Asia').removeAttr('disabled');

    }
});
```

For Dynamic content (includes and element dom creation after page load) use live.
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of room for tightening the following code up, but it works:

```
$('#International').click(function() {
    var paramChangeBoxes = $('input:checkbox');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if (!$('#Americas').is(':checked')) {
            $('#Americas').click();
        }
        $('#Americas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        if (!$('#Europe').is(':checked')) {
            $('#Europe').click();
        }
        $('#Europe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        if (!$('#Asia').is(':checked')) {
            $('#Asia').click();
        }
        $('#Asia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        paramChangeBoxes.removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#Americas').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#Europe').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#Asia').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow - thank you! I combined yours with John's first line of code (which included the "live" coding) and now it works like a well oiled machine!